# VS 2008 C# : Class library is not accessible in another class library in same solution

Tags: c#, reference, project

I have a solution in VS 2008 which has one web project and 3 Class libraries as 3 different Projects.  One project is for DataAccess and one is for BusinessLogic.

I have a class in DataAccessLayer.  From there when I am trying to access the Class of BusinessLogic class library (project) it is not coming in the IntelliSense when I type.  I used the same namespace in both projects.  Still same results.

Do I need to to create DLLs for the first project and add as reference to second?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to add reference to this project in another project in your soultion. 
Visual studio has an option to add project as a reference, so you don't have to add assembly files directly

Comment: The classes also have to be publicly available.

Answer (score 5):

You need to reference the library in the other projects.

To do that, right-click the references folder in the Solution Explorer, click Add Reference, go to the Projects tab, and select the library that you want to reference.

**EDIT**: Also, make sure that the class you are trying to use is declared as `public` (eg, `public class MyClass`).

If you leave out the `public` modifier (which is the default), the class will only be usable in its project.  To expose classes and members to other projects, add the `public` modifier to their declaration

Comment: Hey! Did you steal my answer?! 8^D

Answer (score 2):

You'll need to add a reference to the project containing the `BusinessLogic` class in the `DataAccess` project. Otherwise, the compiler doesn't have anyway of finding the implementation of your `BusinessLogic` class, even if it does use the same namespace.

Answer (score 1):

This may sound silly, but have you specified the class in question as Public or Friend? They'll need to be "shared" in that sense in order to be properly picked up and used within the other applications, even when the project reference is specified.